# How to split a String and to assign the split values to an array?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Delimiter = "#";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Type in the number of names that you would like to store.");
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Input the " +n+" names in the following format: "
            + "name/lastname#");

    String theNames = scan.next();

    Scanner strScan = new Scanner(theNames);
    strScan.useDelimiter(Delimiter);

    String [] s = new String[n];

    Name [] testArray = new Name[n];


    int i=0;
    while(strScan.hasNext()){

        s[0]= strScan.next().split("/");
        s[1]= strScan.next().split("/");
        testArray[i]=new Name(s[0],s[1]);
        i++;

    }
```

The problem is that I cannot split the firstname and the lastname that are separated by "/". I want to assign s[0] to first name and s[1] to the lastname.

Comment: You have a logical error in your code. You ask for "n" as the number of firstname / lastname pairs but use it to initialize the array used to store first and lastname. if you enter 1 on your number of names question, your code would fail with a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you have double error :  compile error and a logical error. When you call

```
    s[0]= strScan.next().split("/");
    s[1]= strScan.next().split("/");
```

it will give a compile error , the split("/") method return an array of String.
if we suppose that you do

```
    s[0]= strScan.next().split("/")[0];
    s[1]= strScan.next().split("/")[1];
```

then you will get in s[0] the fisrtname of the of the first person ,and in s[1] the last name of the second person.

you have to call instead

```
String[] datas=strScan.next().split("/");
s[0]=data[0];
s[1]=data[1];
```

or just

```
s=strScan.next().split("/");
```

Comment: There is a typo in your third code block (`s[2]` instead of `s[1]`). Also see my comment on the question, `s` is mis-initialized. Your short example (4th code section), however would be sufficient and correct.

Answer (score 0):

use the split method of the String class, this will do exactly what you need.

this works like a charm:

```
String names= "Jan/Albert/Bob";
    String[] ns = names.split("/");
    for ( String name : ns ){
    System.out.println(name);
    }
```

how is your split - code?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arr= theNames.split("/")
s[0]= aar[0]
s[1]= arr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

`Split` returns array so get values using index [0],[1]

```
   while(strScan.hasNext()){

        s[0]= strScan.next().split("//")[0];
        s[1]= strScan.next().split("//")[1];
        testArray[i]=new Name(s[0],s[1]);
        i++;

    }
```

However you don't need to put it in another array, split itself returns array.